# Error creating table stored as Textfile from view

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to load information from a view into an Hive table stored as textfile configured like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
field1 BIGINT
,field2 STRING
,email STRING
,field3 BIGINT
,field4 STRING
) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE ;
```

The thing is that after i created the table i insert the info from the view like this:

```
insert into table1 as 
select 
field1 
,field2 
,email 
,field3 
,field4 
from v_table2 ;
```

The process returns success but when i check the data on table1 the select statement returns the following output:

```
Error converting column: 4 to BIGINT
```

The information on that field returns Null when there is info on that field on the view but the insert statement doesn't return any error.

Besides, i can load the first BIGINT field correctly but the email fields displays a "square" and the BIGINT field after that gives that error.
Checking the data on the file it seems that the information suffers a shift after the email field.

Sounds like some encoding problem.

Already tried to force the encoding like this but the no luck:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 SET SERDEPROPERTIES('serialization.format'='\u0001', 'serialization.encoding'='windows-1252');
```

I should also mention that the fields that are being loaded into table1 from the view are already BIGINT in the table that the view loads information from.

Anyone can help ?

---

### Solution

After some research i manage to found a solution by creating a the destination table with the following definition:

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('separatorChar'='\u0001', 'quoteChar'="'", 'escapeChar' = '\\')
STORED AS TEXTFILE
```

And by treating the data on the field "email" like that:

```
case 
    when ascii(email_fe) <> 1 
    then email_fe 
    else NULL 
end email_fe
```

for the "email" fields where the strange data appears i checked that the **ascii** code was always **1** and by checking that on the select statement i could treat the information accordingly and get the data on the table for the other fields inserted the right way.

Does anyone have a better alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a try this please? This error is thrown since the table created has a column of bigint and we are trying to insert an int value

insert into table1 as 
select 
field1 
,field2 
,email 
,cast(field3 as bigint)
,field4 
from v_table2 ;

Comment: I have tried that but with no luck. The thing is that the field "email" is showing some strange character on it and somehow it is making the interpreter read the info on that field as it was the data from two fields what makes the info in the table from the "email" field forward to shift one cell to the right

Comment: Try to allow only alphanumeric values into the insert statement like below




insert into table1 as select field1 ,field2 ,REGEXP_REPLACE(email, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', ''), cast(field3 as bigint) ,field4 from v_table2 ;


You may also amend the regex_replace if you want to avoid replacing few spl characters like @.